# Styles(css) not working for React app inside shadow DOM

Tags: reactjs, webpack, google-chrome-extension, shadow-dom

I'm working on a chrome extension using react. I injected the react app into a shadow host, so that the extension does not disturb the website's DOM. The React application is working fine, but the styles are not applying. I used [react-shadow](https://github.com/Wildhoney/ReactShadow) for injecting react into shadow DOM. In the screenshot, you can see that the style tag is rendered inside the shadow DOM, still the styles are not applying:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You can't style the host's parent element from inside ShadowDOM. You can style only the host itself and only by using `:host { ... }` selector.

Comment: I want to style the inner components. I tried like this https://codesandbox.io/s/react-shadow-by6bo?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

I understood your problem. I had ever been in that trouble with svg and css.
Recently I have been developed chrome extension with react-shadow.
Shadowdom is isolated with real dom so that you can not applied css style for this dom generally.
I will write my code for you. I hope it would be helpful.
You need to create custom.d.ts file for using css file as a component.

```
// custom.d.ts file 

declare module '*.svg' {
  import * as React from 'react';

  export const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<
     React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>
  >;

  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
declare module '*.css'
declare module '*.scss'
```

Now you can import any css file if you want.

```
// contentScript.tsx file

import styles from "./assets/css/styles.css";
import HomePanel from "./components/widgets/HomePanel";
const App: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <>
           <style>{styles}</style>
           <HomePanel />
        </>
    ) 
}
// Render the App component inside the shadow root using createRoot
const sidebarRoot = createRoot(shadowRoot);
sidebarRoot.render(<App />);
```

At last, need to change webpack.config.js file.

```
// frist install raw-loader library 
npm install --save-dev raw-loader
// insert rule in webpack.config.js
module:{
   rules: [{
       test: /\.css$/,
       use: [{
          loader: 'raw-loader',
          options: {
             esModule: false,
          },
       }],
       include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/css'),
          /node_modules/,
       ],
   }]
}
```

Please try with this and feel free to ask if any trouble.

Comment: In additional, you need to use Webpack for building the extension.
Please insert this rule in webpack.config.js

{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [{
        loader: 'raw-loader',
        options: {
            esModule: false,
        },
    }],
    include: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/css'),
        /node_modules/,
    ],
};